# how to add extra data into create method with laravel

Tags: laravel-5

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $user = Book::create([
    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
    'name => $request->name,
    'year => $request->year
 )];
}
```

The above code is able to store into Database.

I want to know how to add below extra data TOGETHER.
I found out that merge was not working as it is not collection.
Tried to chain but was not working.

```
public function data() {
  $array = [
      'amount' => 30,
      'source' => 'abcdef',
  ];

  return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch create Event in Model. 
This code may can help you.

```
/**
 * to set default value in database when new record insert
 *
 */
public static function bootSystemTrait()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->amount = 30;
    });
}
```

You can write this code into your model. It will execute every time when you create record using Laravel model.

If you want to modify it you can use property into Model class. Something like this:

```
class TestClass extends Model
{
    public static $amount = 0;

    static::creating(function ($model) {
          $model->amount = self::$amount;
    });
}
```

Good Luck.